# Can I set-up Springsource ToolSuite (STS) or Eclipse to pick up my Network ID and password for Internet Access

Tags: eclipse, kerberos, ntlm, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When using Eclipse (3.6.*) or STS (2.6.* or 2.8.*, based on Eclipse 3.6.*) you need to set-up proxy entries in order to be able to access the internet.

This can be a pain so I'd like to be able to set-up the entry to automatically detect the userID and password.

I presume that this can be done as we used to have to enter our ID and password for internet access when using IE, or Firefox, but this is now done for us using Kerberos.

I've been told that if Eclipse links to Kerberos or NTLM - Then we can set up the proxy.

So does anyone know if Eclipse will link into Kerberos or NTLM ? and if so, how do we do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the preference page Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.  You can set your proxy and other network information here.